# Internationalize plugin so strings can be translated in WPML

Tags: translation, plugin-wpml, localization

A third party developer made a text widget with title, body and thumbnail. This accompany widget plugin has not been internationalized and therefore the strings do not appear in WPML's string translation management. I need them to be loaded. 
So I am trying to register the plugings domain as indicated [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers), but the code I added:

```
function accompany_text_init() {
    $plugin_dir = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'accompany-text', false, $plugin_dir );
}
add_action('init', 'accommpany_text_init');
```

does not load. It seems as the widget is not registered. [Here is the full code](http://pastebin.com/81wKEitR). What am I doing wrong? Is the call position off? A plugin coding newbie here and a junior PHP-er so would appreciate some help.

Comment: Could you please clean up the code of the pastebin? It's actually unreadable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some great help - even though a bit late - from the guys at [WPML](http://wpml.org/), especially @Brooks I managed to ge the code fixed. The icl_register_strings() function was in the wrong place so WPML I shifted it to the update() Method from where one can sanitize the instance variables before they are used by the widget. 
The icl_t() function was put in the widget() Method. The widget() which is used to display content within the widget when it appears in the sidebar on your blog.
They also changed one of the $name argument of icl_register_string($context, $name, $value) to 'widget body – ' . $this->id so we can now  have unique values stored for that value. Code can be seen here: https://github.com/jasperf/Accompany-Widget

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [translation functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

Example:

```
_e( 'Number', 'accompany-text' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the following

```
$plugin_dir = basename(dirname(__FILE__)); 
load_plugin_textdomain( 'accompany-text', false, $plugin_dir );
```

inside where the widget class is initialised. In your example, inside the `AccompanyPostWidget` function.

That said, there doesn't appear to be any text strings that are translatable in the widget class you've linked to. For instance, to translate the word number (as in Toscho's answer)

```
<?php _e( 'Number', 'accompany-text' ); ?>
```

As a more complete example, the following loads the text domain and makes the Widget description translatable:

```
 function AccompanyPostWidget(){
    $plugin_dir = basename(dirname(__FILE__)); 
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'accompany-text', false, $plugin_dir );
    $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'AccompanyPostWidget', 'description' => __( 'Displays a Accompany post with thumbnail','accompany-text');
    $this->WP_Widget('AccompanyPostWidget', 'Accompany Text Widget', $widget_ops);
  }
```

**Side remark**

The following would 'normally' be sufficient, but isn't loaded in time to translate the widget's title and description:

```
function accompany_text_init() {
    $plugin_dir = basename(dirname(__FILE__));
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'accompany-text', false, $plugin_dir );
}
add_action('init', 'accompany_text_init');
```

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that I have not added any gettext calls. Silly me. Working on that now.

Comment: Updated the pastie, but I only get an error when I added the domain initiation to the widget class. 'Warning: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'accommpany_text_init' was given in /wp-includes/plugin.php on line 405'

Comment: You need to remove the function and the add_action that was in the question from your code and just add those two lines from my answer inside AccompanyPostWidget

Comment: Done that. Updated pastie. Code is added to function AccompanyPostWidget() and I have added one __():
?php printf(__($this->get_field_id('text'))); ?> Nothing loaded yet but no errors either

Comment: That's because you are trying to translate the field's ID rather than it's label text. See Toscho's answer, but I shall edit my answer.

Comment: can't see anything gettext from the file in the pastebin

Comment: On line 35 (code: http://pastebin.com/81wKEitR )I used gettext call __() as seen http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress and http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers using printf to echo it as I have variables there. That does not seem to work. Checking all once more now

Comment: Like I said, you are translating the fields ID (as in the id attribute of html tag), see my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, pastie wasn't updated. Checked you updated answer. Using printf(__(attribute_escape($d)), $text); for the text area now. I cannot use e_ as I work witha variable in the text area that loads the text. But it seems the text like this is not loaded in the widget in the Dashboard not does it get loaded as a string. I guess the $d variable used in the sample is only for comment spam..

Comment: You can't translate user input, only known strings. Such as the labels, 'Number', or the widget description.

Comment: With WPML I am supposed to be able to grab text and translate that as I can do with text in pages, posts and custom posts. See http://wpml.org/documentation/support/translation-for-texts-by-other-plugins-and-themes/ , but now that I am reading it again it all seems more complicated..

Comment: Asked WPML a question about it. Will wait and see

Comment: Well, with some help form WPML I made progress. Was able to register the string: `icl_register_string('Accompany Text','Widget Text', $text);` and `echo attribute_escape (icl_t('Accompany Text','Widget Text', $text));`  and get it to load the string from WPML string management. Somehow the final widget text is stored/grabbed by WPML and the initial two are not. Not sure yet why. Updated code here: http://pastebin.com/gy6CNwUT